# Qooxdoo -- Is there a way to delete an offline store by key?

Tags: qooxdoo

In Qooxdoo, is there a way to delete an offline store by its key? 'resetModel' doesn't appear to get rid of the entry and I couldn't find any other options that looked applicable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats possible with the upcoming 2.0 release. We fixed a bug which covered exactly that:
http://bugzilla.qooxdoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6000